# How to turn this POST cURL request into a java code

Tags: spring, rest

I have the following cURL request that I want to turn into java code to execute it with spring.

I use it to upload a file, the cURL request works correctly.

```
 curl "https://mywebsite.service-now.com/api/now/attachment/file?table_name=incident&table_sys_id=fa4922f6db3ea30085a0f7871d961999&file_name=test.zip" --request POST --header "Accept:application/json" --header "Authorization:Basic cmVhbHRlc3QyOmJwb3N0QDEyMw==" --header "Content-Type: application/zip" -F "uploadFile=@test.zip"
```

I will use the following API:

```
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/inbound_rest/reference/r_AttachmentAPI-POST.html
```

I made a little research and found out that I have to use restTemplate to use 3rd party API.

I also wrote this:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodePassword());
    return headers;
```

(I made the encodePassword method, that is correct. )

I tried a lot of other stuff but it doesn't work

Comment: Try to get the curl request to work with Postman. Once it works, click on the 'code' option in Postman, and select Java. This will convert your POST request to Java code.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't really work when I have to integrate it with Spring. That's why I think I should use Spring's resttemplate. That's how I succesfully use the API for get requests.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `content-type header` value to `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`. When this header is set, `RestTemplate` automatically marshals the file data along with some metadata.

```
//Headers

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

//parameter values
// the getTestFile( ) method generates a file on the fly and returns a FileSystemResource

MultiValueMap<String, Object> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("file", getTestFile();
...

//create request
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity( url, request , String.class );
```

Comment: Where do we add the file? Suppose it is in my resources folder

Comment: I mean the part after -F ( uploadFile=...)

Comment: see my updated answer, hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Now we've added the file but removed the others... Can't we have both? Because in the curl command we have both. Am I wrong?